# How to sed or grep something between 2 special characters and modify the output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, sh

i want to grep or sed anything between ! and ?
For example

`!X hello my name is X?`

with X being a Number between 0-9
and Output it to

```
Xhello my name isX
```

I want of course get all this Patterns in the text file and cut out anything else

Example:

```
blabla
foo bar !3 whats up 3?
!4 hello im new
to this forum 4?
foo bar now
```

Result:

```
3whats up3
4hello im new to this forum4
```

Maybe someone can help me, i only want to use sh and this commands

Comment: *anything between ! and ?* - and what if there would be a line `!4 hello im new!1 why? 2?` ? how it should be treated?

Comment: Assume that ! and ? will never be used bewteen

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have an input file with contents (was intentionally complicated to cover extended situations):

```
blabla !1
foo bar !3 whats up 3?
sdfsdf
sdf !33333?
!4 hello im new
to this forum 4?
foo bar now
!344 dd!4 sdf?fff 44?
```

---

Two approaches:

-- ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -v RS='!' 'match($0,/^([0-9]) ([^!?]*) ([0-9])?/,a){ gsub(/\n/,"",a[2]); print a[1]a[2]a[3] }' file
```

- `-v RS='!'` - considering `!` as record separator
- `match($0,/^([0-9]) ([^!?]*) ([0-9])?/,a)` - matching needed sequences and placing captured groups `(..)` values into array `a`

---

-- ***paste*** + ***grep*** + ***sed*** pipeline:

```
paste -d' ' -s file | grep -o '![0-9] [^!?]* [0-9]?' | sed -En 's/!([0-9]+) (.*) ([0-9]+)\?/\1\2\3/p'
```

- `paste -d' ' -s file` - merge lines of *file* using space as delimiter
- `grep -o '![0-9] [^!?]* [0-9]?'` - search and output only needed sequences matching the pattern
- `sed -En 's/!([0-9]+) (.*) ([0-9]+)\?/\1\2\3/p'` - perform substitutions under the captured groups

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
3whats up3
4hello im new to this forum4
```

Answer (score 1):

A single `awk` command that, while not trivial, is efficient:

```
awk '
  {
    from = match($0, "![0-9] ")
    if (from) {
      $0 = substr($0, from+1, RLENGTH-2) substr($0, from + RLENGTH)
    }
    to = match($0, " [0-9]\\?")
    if (to) {
      $0 = substr($0, 1, to-1) substr($0, to+1, length($0)-to-1)
    }
    if (from && to)  print
    else if (from)   printf "%s ", $0
    else if (to)     print
  }
' file
```

Note: The assumption is that no `!<digit> ... <digit>?` sequence spans more than 2 lines (it wouldn't be hard to adapt the solution to that case).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
$ cat file2
blabla
foo bar !3 whats up 3?
!4 hello im new
to this forum 4?
foo bar 2345 now

$ awk -v RS="[!?]" '{gsub("\n"," ")}$0 ~ /^[0-9].*[0-9]$/{sub(" ","");print gensub(/ ([0-9]$)/,"\\1","g")}' file2
3whats up3
4hello im new to this forum4
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & tr):

```
tr '\n!?' ' \n\n' < file |
sed -nr '/^([0-9]).*\1$/s/^([0-9])\s*|\s*([0-9])$/\1\2/gp'
```

Translate newlines to spaces and `!` and `?` to newlines. Then check that each line begins and ends with the same number and if so remove any space after or before above numbers and print the result.

Can be done in two sed invocations as:

```
sed -z 'y/\n!?/ \n\n/' file |
sed -nr '/^([0-9]).*\1$/s/^([0-9])\s*|\s*([0-9])$/\1\2/gp'
```

or:

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;y/\n!?/ \n\n/' file | 
sed -nr '/^([0-9]).*\1$/s/^([0-9])\s*|\s*([0-9])$/\1\2/gp'
```

or as one:

```
sed -nr '/\n/ba;H;$!d;x;y/\n!?/ \n\n/;s/^([0-9])\s*|\s*([0-9])$/\1\2/Mg;:a;/^([0-9])[^\n]*\1\n/P;D' file
```